# Alternative of ORACLE SYS_XMLGEN in postgres or Postgres Plus Advanced Server

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am migrating a oracle project to postgres project 
if there is any alternative to 
ORACLE  SYS_XMLGEN  in postgres or Postgres Plus Advanced Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SYS_XMLGEN is a properitary function see [XML functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-xml.html) for similar functionality, [SQL/XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/XML) or XML-Related Specifications is part 14 of the Structured Query Language (SQL) has limited support from the major DBMS implementation and is what you should use.

for example

```
SELECT xmlforest('abc' AS foo, 123 AS bar);

xmlforest
------------------------------
 <foo>abc</foo><bar>123</bar>


SELECT xmlforest(table_name, column_name)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'pg_catalog';

xmlforest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <table_name>pg_authid</table_name><column_name>rolname</column_name>
 <table_name>pg_authid</table_name><column_name>rolsuper</column_name>
```